# Should I provide payslips if my salary is deposited into bank account?

Tags: paperwork, italy, tourist-visas

I just want to ask about the required financial documents for the tourism visa to Italy.

It's mentioned that we should provide a pay slips of the last 6 months. What do they mean by pay slips?

If it's regarding to salary, it's automatically transferred into my bank account. I don't receive any pay slips from my work. What should I provide instead? If the bank statement is showing my salary, is it okay not to provide this paper?

Thanks

Comment: That's a bit unusual, at least from the USA and UK perspective. Most companies which do a direct deposit to your account also give you a pay slip so you know what is going into your account, income tax, social security deductions etc.

Comment: Does your employer give you anything to document the transaction? It can be an email, the paperwork used to set up the transaction into your back. In the absence of anything else, have your employer write a statement, on company letterhead, that you are an employee, that your salary is xx amount, that it direct deposits xx amount into your account every week/bi-weekly/month.

Comment: Actually in UAE we don't receive anything like that we only revive a SMS from the bank to confirm the deposit.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Italy, and any Schengen visa visit visa applications, required documents include a letter from an employer that states your position, the basic and gross monthly salary, date(s) of employment, and confirmation of leave/vacation granted.
This, accompanied by the also-required bank statements, should satisfy the need to demonstrate your financial circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

### What do they mean by `pay slip`?

To keep on the question. A pay `slip` ("busta paga") is neither underwear (humour mode on) or an envelope with plenties of **cash**. It's a periodic statement from your employer, tyipically monthly, that summarizes how much you have been paid.

It is considered mandatory by labour law and certifies:

- That you are currently employed
- That your employer paid taxes to the local government
- How much you are being paid

Italian authorities would only care for #1 and #3 in order to prove your financial autonomy. If you empty your bank account on a monthly basis at the casino and won't have money to afford food and transport in the visiting country, it is your private business.

In absence of a pay slip, you must provide supplementary documentation from your employer.